# Dynamically edit the InnerHtml of a List Item without overwriting everything in the <li> tag

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a list item that contains an a href and a link button:

```
<li runat="server" id="liActivityInvoices">
   <a href="#tabActivityInvoices">Invoices</a>
   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnLoadInvoice" OnClick="btnInvoiceActivity_Click"  CssClass="btnListSmall" Width="90px"></asp:LinkButton>
</li>
```

In the code behind I want to update the `a href` to show the revenue from invoices found. So I tried using this:

```
liActivityInvoices.InnerHtml = "<a href=\"#tabActivityInvoices\">Invoices (" + Company.Current.DefaultCurrency + ": " + Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["CurTotalRev"]) + ")</a>";
```

This works but it overwrites everything within the `<li>` tag so I lose the link button. Is there a way to just edit the `a href` part and keep the link button?

Comment: Replace it with a `Label` or `Literal` Control and set the Text.

Comment: $("#liActivityInvoices").find("a").text("your new text")

Comment: @VDWWD thanks that worked

Answer (score 0):

```
li#ActivityInvoices.InnerHtml = "<a href=\"#tabActivityInvoices\">Invoices (" + Company.Current.DefaultCurrency + ": " + Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["CurTotalRev"]) + ")</a>";
```

try this one